# Get values from an infinite loop

Tags: java, multithreading, infinite-loop

I have 5 threads running in an infinite loop. I need to fetch the final value after all 5 threads end every time. How can I do this?

```
while(true){
        new Class1(1,10).start();
        new Class1(11,20).start();
        new Class1(21,30).start();
        new Class1(31,40).start();
        new Class1(41,50).start();
    }
```

I need to determine the end of these 5 threads and pick one particular value updated in all the threads. How can I do this?

Comment: add a join. Write the values to an array.

Comment: @elyashiv Add a join? I have heard about join but haven't tried it yet. I will look into that and let you know if that works for me. Can you give me some simple examples for join meanwhile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code here is going to start 5 new threads every single time around the loop and keep looping constantly. Are you absolutely sure that's what you want?

Just use a `CountDownLatch` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html

Initialize the latch at 5. Each thread counts the latch down once when it exits.

The main thread waits for the latch to hit 0 then does its processing and exits.

Do not loop creating threads!

Comment: I know my code launches 5 threads every time. I am kind of doing a monitory system so I need those. I have not heard about  CountDownLatch. I will definitely see if it works for me and let you know.

Comment: @Parthe You aren't creating 5 threads every time you run. You are creating thousands, maybe even millions. However many that while loop manages to create before everything slows to a crawl...

Comment: so what do you suggest instead of this if I need continuous monitoring say for ports. I mean for checking open ports in system continuously from start of the day to end of the day

Comment: Won't that increase run time?

Comment: I changed it to a single thread and run it once it works fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(true){
  List<Class1> x = Arrays.asList( new Class1(1,10), new Class1(11,20), new Class1(21,30), new Class1(31,40), Class1(41,50));
  for (Class1 t: x) {
    x.start();
  }
  for (Class1 t: x) {
    x.join();
  }
}
```

Comment: i don't understand what you have done in the above code. Can you please explain it to me?